# SED command to delete last line in a remote host

Tags: ssh, sed

I have the following running one liner to delete last injected ED key from last line of authorized keys folder of a remote host.

```
sed -i '${/^\(ssh-ed25519\) \(.*\) \([A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*@hpe\.com\)$/d;}' .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I do a couple of operations after creating ED key and injecting it into remote host. Then I want to clear up as tear down step. However when I tried to run it by connecting to remote host it failed. I tried the following things:

```
ssh -T 'sh -c "sed command here"'  # too many single and double quotes, so I gave up
```

Then I tried removing T terminal and as well as "sh -c" command running part

```
ssh root@my_remote_host "sed -i '${/^\(ssh-ed25519\) \(.*\) \([A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*@hpe\.com\)$/d;}' .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

had this error:

```
sed: couldn't open temporary file .ssh/sedWC1YAQ: Read-only file system
```

I referred to this link but it also didn't help : [Using SED in a ssh command on a remote node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695943/using-sed-in-a-ssh-command-on-a-remote-node)

I appreciate any help, and let me know if what I'm trying is a good way to apply.

Comment: When I run the command `echo ssh root@my_remote_host "sed -i '${/^...' .ssh/authtorized_keys"` in bash I get a "bad substitution" error. The shell is taking the `${...}` as a parameter to expand. Try simply removing the double quotes: it's OK to send multiple arguments like `ssh host cmd arg ...`

Comment: what is output of `ssh root@my_remote_host 'touch .ssh/test; rm .ssh/test'`?

Comment: `touch: cannot touch '.ssh/test': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '.ssh/test': No such file or directory`
So I think now I have to think about removing the injected ED public key. Wont cause a harm I think if I leave it, next time I should not create another ED priv./pub key pair