# sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: git

I have added alias in my .gitconfig

```
  rnd      =  !sh -c \"git commit -m '$(curl -s http://whatthecommit.com/index.txt)'\"
```

And now when I type

```
git add . && git commit rnd
```

I get an error
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings

Answer (score 1):

You have your quoting backward a bit... you want to single-quote the command to run, pass that to sh, and use the backslash-quoted double quotes around your string expansion...

```
rnd = !sh -c 'git commit -m \"$(curl -s http://whatthecommit.com/index.txt)\"'
```

And also, just a note, in your question you call `git commit rnd`, but in reality, you would call this as `git rnd`.

Comment: Inside single quotes, one does need not to escape doublt quotes. That is, `... 'git commit -m "$(curl ... index.txt)"'` should be just fine.

Comment: @kostix I tested this before I posted the answer, and the non-escaped quotes do not work. I assume this is because one more interpolation is performed along the way than one would expect.