# How do I change the temporary root MySQL password using a bash shell script?

Tags: mysql, bash, quotes, single-quotes, mysqladmin

I need to change the temporary root password that is created when the MySQL daemon is started. The problem is that the temporary password has some weird characters (e.g. like a left/right parenthesis) that needs to be escaped. Now, there are several posts ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644092/bash-script-and-escaping-special-characters-in-password), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell)) on how to escape characters, in general, but this post is in the context of using a bash script to change the temporary MySQL root password that may have *special* characters.

Currently, my script looks like the following.

```
function startMysql {
    sudo service mysqld start
    echo "started mysql"

    export PW=$(grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $11}')
    # export PASS=\'$PW\'
    echo "temporary password is $PW"
    mysqladmin -u root -p$PW password aaBB@@cc1122
    # the following doesn't work either
    # mysqladmin -u root -p$PASS password aaBB@@cc1122
    echo "changed mysql password"
}
```

Note that the temporary password may look like the following.

- BYkc*),ZM3-_

If I type in the following on the terminal, it works.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p'BYkc*),ZM3-_' password aaBB@@cc1122
```

But inside the script, it fails. Here are some ways that I have tried to put single quotes around `$PW` without success.

- `mysqladmin -u root -p"'$PW'" password aaBB@@cc1122`
- `mysqladmin -u root -p\''$PW'\' password aaBB@@cc1122`
- `mysqladmin -u root -p"$PW" password aaBB@@cc1122`
- `mysqladmin -u root -p"\"$PW\"" password aaBB@@cc1122`

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `echo "temporary password is $PW"` give you? `mysqladmin -u root -p"$PW" password aaBB@@cc1122` should work just fine.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: the echo to the console shows as correct. but I still get authentication failure as if I passed in the wrong password.

Answer (score 2):

It does work for me using double-quotes:

```
password=$(grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $11}')
mysqladmin --user=root --password="$password" password aaBB@@cc1122
```