# getting stuck at saving a string

Tags: php, json, string, curl

i get a encoded string when saving a string
When i save:

```
'FFFA
```

i get:

```
&#39;FFFA
```

how can i save them using the ff curl request:

```
curl "https://api.adbutler.com/v1/banners/custom-html" \
-H "Authorization: Basic {API_KEY}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d '{  
      "custom_html": "",
      "expand_horizontal_direction": "left",
      "expand_vertical_direction": "down",
      "height": 250,
      "html_content_below": "Hello 'world",
      "location": "http://www.google.ca",
      "name": "Demo Custom HTML' Banner",
      "tracking_pixel": "url",
      "width": 300
    }'
```

Comment: use `html_entity_decode()` for each your string

Comment: it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

set another curl option for  `CURLOPT_ENCODING` and set it to "" to ensure it will not return any garbage

```
     $location = 'https://api.adbutler.com/v1/banners/custom-html';
$ch = curl_init($location);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
curl "https://api.adbutler.com/v1/banners/custom-html" \
-H "Authorization: Basic {API_KEY}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d '{  
  "custom_html": "",
  "expand_horizontal_direction": "left",
  "expand_vertical_direction": "down",
  "height": 250,
  "html_content_below": "Hello '\''world",
  "location": "http://www.google.ca",
  "name": "Demo Custom HTML'\'' Banner",
  "tracking_pixel": "url",
  "width": 300
}'
```

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings) for more info