# How get git commit hash by it number (--count)

Tags: git

I get a position of commit by command

```
git rev-list HEAD --count
```

For example, output is 1164. I want checkout to this commit number. How can I do this? I think, need get hash of this commit and checkout to commit by it hash.

Comment: Git is not made to work with commit number which is also wrong because you could have multiple commit with this count number. Use the hash which is the only unique id.

Comment: Hmm... what commit do you denote by *"commit #1164"*? The first one displayed by `git rev-list`? Or the last one?

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution:

```
git rev-list HEAD --reverse | nl | grep <your build number>
```

`git rev-list HEAD --reverse` prints out all the commit hashes from oldest to newest. `nl` prefixes each line with a line number (effectively the `count`). And finally, good ol' `grep` filters to just the line you want.

You could further refine this to just the commit hash with `awk`:

```
git rev-list HEAD --reverse | nl | grep <your build number> | awk '{print $2}'
```

or take it to the next level with a git alias:

```
git config --global alias.build-number '!f() { git rev-list HEAD --reverse | nl | grep $1 | awk '"'"'{print $2}'"'"'; }; f'
```

Alias usage:

```
git build-number <your build number>
```

That quoting madness in the git config command above is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/320737

Answer (score 3):

By adding `--count` to the `git rev-list` command line you tell it to not display the revisions list but only the number of revisions it would display without the `--count` argument.

Basically `git rev-list HEAD --count` and `git rev-list HEAD | wc -l` produce the same output (the number of lines in the output of `git rev-list HEAD`).

---

The answer to your question depends on what exactly do you mean by *"commit #1164"*.

If you count the commits as they are listed by `rev-list` then the first commit is the current commit (aka `HEAD`) and commit #1164 is the oldest commit that is reachable starting from `HEAD`. To get its hash, don't tell `git rev-list` to display the count but let it display the revisions (it displays their hashes) and pipe its output to `tail -1` to get the last hash in the list:

```
git rev-list HEAD | tail -1
```

But please note that by adding a new commit to the current branch, the numbering will change and *commit #1164* will be a different commit.

---

If you count the commits in chronological order, *commit #1* being the first commit created in the repository then *commit #1164* is the current commit. In this case you don't even need to use `git rev-list` (it walks the entire repository but you don't need this). It's enough to use:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

to get the hash of the current commit (`HEAD`).

---

Either way, the number you produced (*1164*) does not have any relevance to Git and it is not associated in any way with any commits. If you check out a different branch that has at least `1164` commits and follow the same procedure you get a different commit as *commit #1164*.

Comment: `git rev-parse` is better for that, no!?!

Comment: I think we understood the question in different manners. And it's highly probable that I'm not the one that understood it correctly :-(

Comment: Sure, if the OP counts the commits in chronological order, *"commit #1164"* on the current branch would be the current commit and there is no need for `git rev-list`, a simple call to `git rev-parse HEAD` is enough, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for yours answers, but it not what I was looking for.
I know that use git --count it`s not good idea, but at the moment we mark our bilds by this method.

I write little bash snippet, that doing what I need.

```
#!/bin/bash
SEARCH=$1
LAST=$(git rev-list HEAD --count)
DIFF=$((LAST-SEARCH))
git rev-list --skip=$DIFF --topo-order HEAD | head -n1
```

Where `SEARCH` it is --count of commit that you what to search.