# combining and processing 2 tab separated files in awk and make a new one

Tags: awk

I have 2 `tab separated` files with 2 columns. column1 1 is number and column 2 is ID. like these 2 examples:

example file1:

```
188 TPT1
133 ACTR2
420 ATP5C1
942 DNAJA1
```

example file1:

```
91  PSMD7
2217    TPT1
223 ATP5C1
156 TCP1
```

I want to find the common rows of 2 files based on column 2 (column ID) and make a new tab separated file in which there are 4 columns: column1 is ID (common ID) column2 is the number from file1, column3 is the number from file2 and column4 is the log2 values of ratio of columns 2 and 3 (which means log2(column2/column3)). for example regarding the ID "TPT1": 1st column is TPT1, column2 is 188, column3 is 2217 and column 4 is log2(188/2217) which is equal to -3.561494.
here is a the expected output:

expected output:

```
TPT1    188 2217    -3.561494
ATP5C1  420 223 0.9133394
```

I am trying to do that in `AWK` using the following code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { n[$2]=$0;next } ($2 in n) { print n[$2 '\t' $1] '\t' $1 '\t' log(n[$1]/$1)}' file1.txt file2.txt  > result.txt
```

this code does not return what I expect. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Comment: thanks. no this is a different one

Comment: No, that's exactly the reason your attempt didn't work, though there are additional problems as well (you don't use `$1 "\t" $2` as a key in `n` so it will be empty). You can't have single quotes in your Awk script if it's in single quotes. Switch to double quotes or a workaround like in the answer you got.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR {n[$2]=$1;next} ($2 in n) {print $2, $1, n[$2], log(n[$2]/$1)/log(2)}' file1 file2 
TPT1    2217    188  -3.5598
ATP5C1  223     420  0.913346
```

Comment: What does the snippet does? Please explain it.

Comment: The changes in comparison with the OP's attempt are very small. You should be able to figure out from the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) to actually merge the files instead of awk:

```
$ join -j2 <(sort -k2 file1.txt) <(sort -k2 file2.txt) |
   awk -v OFS="\t" '{ print $1, $2, $3, log($2/$3)/log(2) }'
ATP5C1  420 223 0.913346
TPT1    188 2217    -3.5598
```

The `join` program, well, joins two files on a common value. It does require the files to be sorted based on the join column, but your examples aren't, hence the inline `sort`ing of the data files. Its output is then piped to awk to compute the `log2` of the numbers of each line and produce tab-delimited results.

---

Alternative using perl which gives you more default precision if you care about that (And don't want to mess with awk's `CONVFMT` variable):

```
$ join -j2 <(sort -k2 a.txt) <(sort -k2 b.txt) |
   perl -lane 'print join("\t", @F, log($F[1]/$F[2])/log(2))'
ATP5C1  420 223 0.913345617745818
TPT1    188 2217    -3.55980420318967
```

Answer (score 0):

awk + sort approach

```
 awk ' { print $0,FILENAME }' ellyx.txt ellyy.txt | sort -k2 -k3 | awk ' {c=$2;if(c==p) { print c,a,$1,log(a/$1)/log(2) }p=c;a=$1 } '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat ellyx.txt
188 TPT1
133 ACTR2
420 ATP5C1
942 DNAJA1

$ cat ellyy.txt
91  PSMD7
2217 TPT1
223 ATP5C1
156 TCP1

$ awk ' { print $0,FILENAME }' ellyx.txt ellyy.txt | sort -k2 -k3 | awk ' {c=$2;if(c==p) { print c,a,$1,log(a/$1)/log(2) }p=c;a=$1 } '
ATP5C1 420 223 0.913346
TPT1 188 2217 -3.5598

$
```