# How can I escape double quotes in the system command in this perl oneliner?

Tags: bash, perl, syntax, quoting

For my edification, I'd like to find out how to escape quotes within the `system` command in the following perl oneliner:

`$ ls -p | grep -v / | perl -lane 'system("echo \"$_\"");'`

without using the `\"` escape sequence, in the manner shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/3367247

(Obviously this command does nothing useful; it just prints filenames that have spaces in them. But it serves to explain my problem succintly.)

I tried the following (pardon the images, but I have found highlighting easiest to decipher the quoting):

1. system command with double quotes: `system("echo "$_"")`
   [image]

Code: `$ ls -p | grep -v / | perl -lane 'system("echo ''"''$_''"''");'`

2. system command with single quotes: `system('echo "$_"')`
   [image]

Code: `$ ls -p | grep -v / | perl -lane 'system('"'"'echo "$_"'"'"');'`

Neither of these work. Is there a way to accomplish this in the manner of the linked answer?

EDIT: I need double-quotes around the `$_` in the echo command because the string in `$_` contains *parentheses*, not because it contains spaces, as I originally thought.

Comment: `perl -lane 'system(qq/echo "$_"/)'`?

Comment: You should also consider passing system a *list* of arguments. That way, you don't have to invoke a shell and quoting is no longer an issue: `system('/bin/echo', $_)` -- https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, I guess my question is more about understanding bash syntax than seeking the best perl solution (although new perl knowledge is always welcome, of course). I thought I understood how single/double quoting works after reading the linked answer, but it fell short in this instance.

Comment: @glennjackman I didn't know you can call `system` with a list, thanks.

Comment: @dqbydt For the first example, you need to insert the backslashes in front of the quotes: `... | perl -lane 'system("echo ''\"''$_''\"''")'` (compare with your original example, the backslash are not part of the shell syntax, but part of the perl argument string passed to `system`)

Comment: For the second example: You cannot use single quotes since `$_` is a perl variable and needs double quotes to be interpolated into the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to find out how to escape quotes within the system command in
>   the following perl oneliner:
>
> ```
> $ ls -p | grep -v / | perl -lane 'system("echo \"$_\"");'
> ```
>
> without using the \" escape sequence, in the manner shown here: [...]

Those examples are for escaping *single* quotes, your example uses *double* quotes `\"$_\"`. In Bash everything within single quote are taken literally (except the single quote itself), the same is not true for that within double quotes. For example a `$` within double quotes are not a literal `$` but indicates that a variable expansion is to follow.

Now, in your command there are three levels of quote interpretation.

- First the outer shell (the command line):

  ```
  perl -lane 'system("echo \"$_\"");'
  ```
- Then the perl interpreter:

  ```
  system("echo \"$_\");
  ```
- Then a second shell (here, Bash is used):

  ```
  echo "xxx"
  ```

where `xxx` is the expansion of `$_` in the `perl` script

Your command does not contain any internal *single* quotes, so there is no need to use the Bash quoting constructs for escaping single quotes, like

```
It's fine  -> 'It'"'"'s fine'
```

or

```
It's fine  -> 'It'\''s fine'
```

Further, you need to escape the double quote in the perl script

```
system("echo \"$_\"")
```

since they are inside double quotes, alternatively you could remove them
since `echo` does not need double quotes here:

```
system("echo $_")
```

would work fine, or you could do as proposed in the comments:

```
system(qq/echo "$_"/)
```

or use the [LIST form of `system` with more than one argument](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

```
system("/bin/echo", $_)
```

However, if you wanted to use single quotes, for example:

```
system('echo ' . $_)
```

you would need to invoke the shell's single quote escapes:

```
'system('"'"'echo ''"' . $_)'
```

or (using double quotes):

```
"system('echo ' . "'$'"_)"
```

Comment: It turns out I _do_ need double quotes in the echo command - but not because the perl string contains spaces, as I originally thought. It's because it contains _parentheses_. So the single-quote form of system needs to be changed to `system('echo "' . $_ . '"')`. And the shell's single quote escape sequence to accommodate that becomes pretty mind-numbing, lol.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post some insights I have gleaned from the helpful comments and the accepted answer (thank you all!). In the original command I posed:
`$ ls -p | grep -v / | perl -lane 'system("echo \"$_\"");'`
there are *two* interpreters: bash, and perl, coming into play:

1. The original command, interpreted by bash, doesn't touch anything within the (sole pair of) single quotes (i.e. everything after the `-lane`) and passes it intact as a script to perl.
2. The perl interpreter then processes this script, which consists of the single `system` command. It is the *perl* interpreter that is responsible for generating the final `echo` command line which is tossed back to bash for interpretation. This final bash command needs to be dynamically generated from `$_`. There are two ways to do this:

   (a) Use the system command with double quotes so that the `$_` gets interpolated [i.e. `system("echo $_")`] But note, the string echoed needs to have `"`s around it because it could contain parentheses. So we need *perl* to emit, in this final *bash* command string, literal `"`s, around the `$_` (which will get expanded by virtue of the outer `"`s, prior to being sent to bash). There are two ways now to accomplish *this*:

   (a-i) Escape the `"` using a `\` to emit literal quotes: `"echo \"$_\""`

   (a-ii) Use the `qq` operator, which demotes the special status accorded to `"`s within a perl string, and which then can be used as normal characters: `qq(echo "$_")`.

   (b) - OR - the other way of generating the final bash command is to use *single* quotes in the `system` command as suggested by @Håkon in his answer: `system('echo ' . $_)`. But we still do need the quotes around `$_` as discussed earlier, so we need to change this  to: `system('echo "' . $_ . '"')`. Now the task reduces to figuring out bash's single-quote escapes to make sure perl sees this string.

The final forms of the perl command are:

2-a-i: `perl -lane 'system("echo \"$_\"");'`

2-a-ii: `perl -lane 'system(qq/echo "$_"/);'`

And finally:

2-b: `perl -lane 'system('"'"'echo "'"'"'.$_.'"'"'"'"'"');'`

This perversion of `'`s and `"`s is what I set out to attain, so MISSION ACCOMPLISHED! :D

Editorial note: From a practical, usability pov, the `qq` form seems most amenable to just pasting the final, desired bash command into the perl `system` call (and you can then just replace filenames with `$_`).