# grep -E with multiple meta characters

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am struggling with a particular regex i need to pass into the grep -E

in plain english, the regex must match the word if it matches both of these two conditions:

- the word begins at the start of the line OR begins with a space character or any of the following "'`(,:;<[{|~
- the word ends in "'),:;>]`}|~ or a space character, OR is at the end of the line.

```
####should be matched#### ignore the red text#########3
suvoo:
:suvoo:
 suvoo 
 suvoo:
suvoo'
suvoo`
`suvoo`
"suvoo"
'suvoo:
 'suvoo "ghj
'suvoo
[suvoo~
{suvoo'
his name was `suvoo'
his name is suvoo and he is 25
```

```
####shouldnt be matched####
asddsuvooaed
:suvo@abc:
suvooo
1suvoo
suvoo1:
```

I'm not sure about why my command does not matched anything, i might have completely misunderstood what needs escaping etc

```
grep -Einr "(^|[[:space:][\"'(,:;<[\`{|~]])suvoo([[:space:][]\"'),:;>\`}|~]]|$)" .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write it as

```
grep -E '(^|[[:space:]"'"'"'`(,:;<[{|~])suvoo([][:space:]"'"'"'),:;>`}|~]|$)'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/YbwCXm)

You misplaced the square brackets, note that `]` inside a bracket expression should be placed at the very beginning. Also, since your quotation marks are mixed, it is safer to use a common [technique to use single quotes inside single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings).

**Details**

- `` [[:space:]"'"'"'`(,:;<[{|~] `` - translates into `` [[:space:]"'`(,:;<[{|~] `` and matches whitespace, `"`, `'`, `` ` ``, `(`, `,`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `[`, `{`, `|` or `~`.
- `` [][:space:]"'"'"'),:;>`}|~] `` translates into `` [][:space:]"'),:;>`}|~] `` and matches `]`, whitespace, `"`, `'`, `)`, `,`, `:`, `;`, `>`, `` ` ``, `}`, `|` or `~`.