# how to escape single quote in `jq`

Tags: json, shell, formatting, jq, quotation-marks

I am trying to format a json string using `jq` with expected output like this:

```
[
  {
    "command": [
      "printf 'this is a text'"
    ]
  }
]
```

However, I cannot get it to work for the single quotes ('), e.g. `$  jq -n '[{"command": ["printf 'this is a text'"]}]'` gives me a compile error.

I also thought about escaping all double quotes e.g. `jq -n "[{\"command\": [\"printf 'this is a text'\"]}]"`, this is fine however the json string is passed in from a function, I can replace all double quotes with `\"` first and then run the jq command but it's not very elegant.

Is there a better way to handle the single quotes inside a json string?

Comment: In Bash, a single quote cannot be explicitly included in a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are four alternatives that should work with a bash or bash-like shell. They can be adapted for other shells as well.

```
jq -n $'[{"command": ["printf \'this is a text\'"]}]'
```

```
cat << EOF | jq .
[{"command": ["printf 'this is a text'"]}]
EOF
```

```
jq --arg cmd "printf 'this is a text'" -n '[{command: [ $cmd ]}]'
```

```
VAR="[{\"command\": [\"printf 'this is a text'\"]}]"
jq -n --argjson var "$VAR" '$var'
```

See also [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)