# Jenkins pipeline shell output not as expected

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, sh

can i know which part i am doing wrong. The file not in server but however, every time i execute it goes to true statement

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages{

       stage('Test') {
           steps{
                script{
                        hasWar = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'sshpass -p ${password} ssh ${username}@123.12.32.33 \'if [ -f /home/nityo/warFile1.war ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi\'')
                        if (hasWar) {
                            echo 'Has war'                            
                        } else {
                            echo 'No war files' 
                        }
                    }
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Groovy quoting rules, but in shell, you can't include a single quote in a single quoted string the way you did, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/3266847).

Comment: i put is as escpae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the script part echos `true` or `false` to the console in the expected conditions, there is one more thing you didn't take into account. In Groovy, every non-empty string evaluates to `true` when used in the context of the `boolean` variable. It's called [Groovy Truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth).

If you want to evaluate string value `false` to an appropriate `boolean` value, you have to use `toBoolean()` method that returns `false` if the string value stores `false` literal, and `true` if it stores `true` literal.

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#toBoolean()

Also, consider adding `trim()` to the `sh()` step so all whitespaces are trimmed from the output when you store it under the `hasWar` variable.

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages{

       stage('Test') {
           steps{
                script{
                        hasWar = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'sshpass -p ${password} ssh ${username}@123.12.32.33 \'if [ -f /home/nityo/warFile1.war ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi\'').trim()
                        if (hasWar.toBoolean()) {
                            echo 'Has war'                            
                        } else {
                            echo 'No war files' 
                        }
                    }
            }
       }
   }
}
```