# single quotes when using psql from command line

Tags: postgresql, psql, single-quotes

I'm trying to run this simple psql command from command line and getting column ns doesn't exists. I'm sure is something pretty silly that I'm missing.

> `psql -U myuser -p 6432 -h myhost -d mydb-c 'update schema.table set column ='NS' where id <> 123;'`

**ERROR:  column "ns" does not exist**

I tried escape E'NS' to 'NS' but didn't work..

Thanks

Comment: Try double quotes `-c "update ... 'NS' where ..."`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, now problem is that I'm executing this from a shell script so I'm not sure how to pass the "". Here's what I'm running:executeSQL $DB "update schema.table set column ='NS' where id <> 123;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a `shell` question, and is answered for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279).

Adapted for your question:

```sh
psql -U myuser -p 6432 -h myhost -d mydb-c 'update schema.table set column ='"'"'NS'"'"' where id <> 123;'
```

Note: sometimes, when you have several levels of passing args to nested shell invocations, it can also be beneficial to use the octal form of single-quote:

```sh
echo "\047"
# '
```