# How to escape quotes in docker exec bash command

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker

I am trying to execute a bash command in docker but I'm having trouble figuring out how to escape the single quotes around the table name `user_mappings` in my command.  I've tried backslashes, double single quotes, and double quoted single quotes.

I know I could get around it if I didn't wrap the command in `bash -c`, but I need that so I can redirect the output to a file in the container.

```
# docker container exec 1b8 bash -c 'psql -c "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name='user_mappings'" > /tmp/output'
ERROR:  column "user_mappings" does not exist
LINE 1: ...* FROM information_schema.tables where table_name=user_mappi...
```

Comment: I would switch to using double quotes in the outer layer... much easier to get the shell to interpret it how you want.  Try this  `docker container exec 1b8 bash -c "psql -c \"SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name='user_mappings'\" > /tmp/output"
`  If you really want to use single quotes... check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings).

Comment: Could you perform this SQL query directly in your application code, instead of via a debug shell?  Or, can you run `psql` directly on your host, without `docker exec` or the `bash -c` wrapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run it from inside the container by

```
docker exec -it postgres_container_name "psql your_connection_string"
```

In your case

```
docker container exec 1b8 bash -c "psql -c \"SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name='user_mappings'\" > /tmp/output"
```