# Docker PSQL Query Issue: "Column <column_name> does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I'm trying to perform a db query through a docker inline command within a shell script.

myscript.sh:

```
docker run -it --rm -c "psql -U ${DB_USER} -d ${DB_NAME} -h ${DB_HOST}\
    -c 'select col1, col2 , col3 from table1\
    where table1.col2 = \"matching_text\" order by col1;'"
```

But I get an odd error:

```
ERROR:  column "matching_text" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ndow where table1.col2 = "matching_t...
```

For some reason when I run this, psql thinks the matching_text in my query is referring to a column name. How would I get around this?

Note: Our database is implemented as a psql docker container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape quotes in docker exec bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129983/how-to-escape-quotes-in-docker-exec-bash-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of post here and other post solved this issue:

1. Need to use single quotes for string query
2. Use double quotes for -c in psql command ([Answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129983/how-to-escape-quotes-in-docker-exec-bash-command))

```
docker run -it --rm -c "psql -U ${DB_USER} -d ${DB_NAME} -h ${DB_HOST}\
    -c \"select col1, col2 , col3 from table1\
    where table1.col2 = 'matching_text' order by col1;\""
```

Answer (score 1):

The Postgres manual explains you need to use single quotes:

> A string constant in SQL is an arbitrary sequence of characters bounded by single quotes ('), for example 'This is a string'. To include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two adjacent single quotes, e.g., 'Dianne''s horse'. Note that this is not the same as a double-quote character (").

See [section 4.1.2.1 of the postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

Double quotes are for table or column identifiers:

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an identifier, never a key word. So "select" could be used to refer to a column or table named "select", whereas an unquoted select would be taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a parse error when used where a table or column name is expected. The example can be written with quoted identifiers like this:
>
> ```
> UPDATE "my_table" SET "a" = 5;
> ```

See section 4.1.1 of the same manual.

Comment: I originally tried with single quotes, but received the same answer. I found my answer after some digging. I'll post a link to it.