# Split string on single quote in jq

Tags: bash, jq

How can I do a split on single quotes?

I was expecting some kind of escape but I've had no luck so far. Have a feeling this might not even be possible.

```
echo "{\"username\": \"hu'lk\"}" | jq -r '.username|split("\'")|join("")'
```

I expect to get `{"username": "hulk"}` but I don't. It wants me to close `pipe dquote>` instead.

I understand that there might be a better way to do it but the conditional replace is nested in a larger jq filter.

Comment: The `'` from the `split` is interfering with the quotes from `jq -r ''`. Try changin to double quotes: `echo "{\"username\": \"hu'lk\"}" | jq -r ".username | split(\"'\") | join(\"\")"`

Comment: @froejo -since this seems to be mainly a shell-related question, it might be a good idea to mention which shell you have in mind, e.g. by selecting a suitable tag.

Comment: The comment by @0stone0 worked for me. I couldn't get it to escape correctly and converted to double quotes around the filter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split("'")` or

```
[splits("[']")]
```

Depending on which shell you use, the special characters in these may need to be escaped, so you might find it more convenient to use jq’s -f command-line option. If using bash, note that:

```
echo $'"\'"'
```

yields

```
"'"
```

For further insights, see e.g. [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

#### gsub

Consider also `gsub("'";"")`