# How to "go build -ldflags" with custom environment variable

Tags: go, environment-variables

I want to print the build time when program starts, like:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var BuildTime string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(BuildTime)
}
```

I tried set an environment variable to current time by `set bt (date)`, make sure `echo $bt` shows the time.

Then build with `go build -ldflags "-X main.BuildTime=$bt"`, but it fails to build and shows the usage of some linker, like:

[image: err]

I tried some system variable like $USER/$PWD/$TERM, like `go build -ldflags "-X main.BuildTime=$USER"`, all work fine, why not work for `$bt` ?

I'm using fish shell, but I also tried bash, same problem.

Comment: I'm using bash and no matter what I try, if the variable contains spaces it just won't work. Maybe try `FLAGS="-X main.BuildTime"; FLAGS="$FLAGS=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M')"; go build -ldflags "$FLAGS"`

Comment: @xarantolus, this should be the answer, and the script for fish shell is `set x (date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S');   set f "-X main.BuildTime=$x";   go build -ldflags "$f"`,  thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `date` has spaces - whereas the other env var's do not.

To account for any variable value that may have spaces, just wrap the build arg with single quotes `'` like so:

```
# go build -ldflags "-X main.BuildTime=$bt"  # spaces in $bt value will lead to parse errors

go build -ldflags "-X 'main.BuildTime=$bt'"
```

---

Note: if the value you're enclosing with single-quotes (`'`) may itself have a single-quote - then the value should be [properly escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings).