# Perl one-liner regex doesn't substitute correctly - returns error

Tags: bash, perl

This is probably something kick-self obvious but I have to ask as I'm not seeing it.

I'm trying to make the following substitution in this text file. I want this:

```
bind_password = 'grafana'
```

to become this:

```
bind_password = ''
```

I've tried using the following regex one-liner on the file that contains the line:

```
$ perl -0pe 's/(bind_password = \')grafana\'/$1\'/g' file.txt
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

When I've tried the regex on regex101, it's worked fine: https://regex101.com/r/0fb4Pu/1. The difference is that I've had to escape the single quotes. I've tried using double quotes instead of single around the regex, as in:

```
perl -0pe "s/(bind_password = ')grafana'/$1'/g" file.txt
```

But while this doesn't return an error, it doesn't do what I want. It instead replaces the string with a single colon, like so:

```
'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The non-regexp, bash part of your question is answered at [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings). tl;dr: you can't use `\'` to do it, use `'"'"'` instead. Alternately, use a double-quoted string, but escape the dollar sign so bash doesn't see it (and substitute it with nothing, because presumably you don't have `$1` defined in your bash environment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```sh
perl -i -pe "s/bind_password = '\Kgrafana(?=')//" file.txt
```

*Details*:

- `-i` - modify the file contents
- `bind_password = '\K` - match `bind_password = '` and remove this text from the match value (so that it stays intact in the file)
- `grafana` - your `grafana` word
- `(?=')`  - followed with `'` (but `'` is not consumed, so it stays in the file intact)

Note:

- You do not need `0` in `-0pe` because your match is not spanning multiple lines
- Escaping single quotes does not work like this, it is simpler to use dobule quotes here around the expression, although sometimes concatenation is the only way to go
- You need no `g` flag since this `perl` works on a line-by-line basis, and processes all lines (`g` is necessary when there are multiple matches per line).

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I'm planning on using multiple such regex matches across a file, and some of them are multi-line, so I think I would need the 0 option, but in any case this is really helpful.