# Is there a way to escape $ and single quotes together in Bash?

Tags: bash, github-actions

I am running the following code, but if `env.body` contains `$`, it will be translated as a variable.

```
printf -v markdown_message_unescaped %b "<${{ env.URL }}|*${{ env.body }}*>\n"
jq -n -r --arg text "$markdown_message_unescaped" '{"text": $text}'|curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @-  ${{ env.URL }}
```

I modified the code to look like the following to escape `$`, but this does not work well if single quotes are included in `env.body`.

```
body='${{ env.body }}'
printf -v markdown_message_unescaped %b "<${{ env.URL }}|*$body*>\n"
jq -n -r --arg text "$markdown_message_unescaped" '{"text": $text}'|curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @-  ${{ env.URL }}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Related: *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a heredoc, which will preserve everything literally (except the chosen `EOF` string). You *must* use the yaml pipe operator to preserve new lines, as they are required for the heredoc syntax.

```
run: |
  markdown_msg=$(
  cat <<"EOF"
  ${{ env.body }}
  EOF
  )
  printf -v markdown_msg %b "$markdown_msg"
  jq --arg text "$markdown_msg" # etc
```

It's important that bash sees `EOF` on a single line, with no leading or trailing whitespace. Indentation in the yaml file will be stripped before it's passed to bash.

Comment: Even if I use heredoc, if env.body has `$` in it, it will be recognized as a variable.

Comment: @NatsukiHoshii Nothing will be expanded by the shell with (quoted) `"EOF"`. Including `$`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It worked. I forgot to add double quotation marks. Thanks!