# how to pass ' in sql which getting triggered from bask script

Tags: sql, bash, unix, google-bigquery

we want to run sql insert in BQ but we are using .sh file for this.
below is our command and its not working as there is ' in my last insert value("Don't")

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --label lm:<local_mkt> --label env:<env_var> '
INSERT INTO `<project>.<dataset_source>.reason_table`(cd,cd1,cd2,cd3,desc,dec1) 
VALUES(1,"DCV","AB","AB","SDF","I Don't")'
```

can anyone help here

Comment: [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Make double single quotes

```
select 'I don''t'
```

Comment: That's the SQL mechanism to insert a single quote, but it doesn't help with the *shell*'s quoting hell.

Comment: @glenn jackman
You are absolutely right thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

Escape character `'` with `\`

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --label lm:<local_mkt> --label env:<env_var> '
INSERT INTO `<project>.<dataset_source>.reason_table`(cd,cd1,cd2,cd3,desc,dec1) 
VALUES(1,"DCV","AB","AB","SDF","I Don\'t")'
```

Comment: bash does not allow single quotes in a single quoted string, not even escaped. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes