# How to pass a parameter to a shell script in nginx lua

Tags: nginx, lua

I'm doing a simple test to see if I can run a shell script in nginx easily. Lua seems a good solution. So I added

```
content_by_lua_block {
   local myvar = "abcd"
   local file = io.popen("myshellscript.sh myvar")
   local result = file:read("*a")
   ngx.say(result)
}
```

in my nginx.conf. In myshellscript.sh, I use echo "#1" to print the value of the parameter. But instead of seeing "abcd", I see "myvar" from the output. So what's the proper way to pass a variable as a parameter to the shell script in nginx lua?
I know os.execute("myshellscript.sh myvar") can do the similar job as popen, but I don't know how to get the output to the stdout or the exit code from the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to substitute `myvar` with the value of your variable - otherwise you're passing the literal string `myvar`. Since `abcd` does not need to be quoted, simply concatenating `myvar` will work for this example:

```lua
local file = io.popen("myshellscript.sh " .. myvar)
```

or for a more robust solution that quotes strings using single quotes:

```lua
local function quote(param)
    return "'" .. param:gsub("'", [['\'']]) .. "'"
end
local file = io.popen("myshellscript.sh " .. quote(myvar))
```

Comment: You may replace `[['"'"']]` with `[['\'']]`

Comment: @LMD Just tried the simple solution. It worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff may I? [Wouldn't this rely on bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16605140/7185318)

Comment: @LMD - The link in your comment is about `$'...'` format, not about `'...'` and `\'`.  You can check in dash: `sh -c "echo 'abc'\''def'"`