# How to insert a string with a two-levels deep nesting of quotes in a H2 database?

Tags: sql, database, h2

I need to insert this string, from the H2 console, with a two-levels deep nesting of quotes.
Since H2 DB uses single quotes, I cannot use double quotes.
I saw this [SO fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1315213/398348) for a string with a nested quote.

I tried to insert, but got this error

`INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(31,'WhoIAmInChrist','NoAnxietyInChrist','Uplifting','God is bigger than our fearful hearts: Isaiah 35:4  '\''Say to those with fearful hearts, '\''Be strong, do not fear; your God will come, he will come with vengeance; with divine retribution he will come to save you'\'' '\'' (NIV).'`)

In the browser console output, I see the error message:

```
INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(31,'WhoIAmInChrist','NoAnxietyInChrist','Uplifting','God is bigger than our fearful hearts: Isaiah 35:4 \"Say to those with fearful hearts, \"Be strong, do not fear; your God will come, he will come with vengeance; with divine retribution he will come to save you'\" '\" (NIV).');

Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(31,'WhoIAmInChrist','NoAnxietyInChrist','Uplifting','God is bigger than our fearful hearts: Isaiah 35:4 \\""Say to those with fearful hearts, \\""Be strong, do not fear; your God will come, he will come with vengeance; with divine retribution he will come to save you'[*]\\"" '\\"" (NIV).')"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Encouragement VALUES(31,'WhoIAmInChrist','NoAnxietyInChrist','Uplifting','God is bigger than our fearful hearts: Isaiah 35:4 \"Say to those with fearful hearts, \"Be strong, do not fear; your God will come, he will come with vengeance; with divine retribution he will come to save you'\" '\" (NIV).') [42000-214] 42000/42000 (Help)
```

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TYPE Category AS ENUM('WhoIAmInChrist','Default')
CREATE TYPE Tone AS ENUM('Default', 'Uplifting', 'Urging', 'Warning', 'Soothing', 'Comforting', 'Inspiring', 'Centering', 'Balanced')
CREATE TYPE Topic AS ENUM('Default', 'AcceptedInChrist', 'SignificantInChrist', 'SecureInChrist', 'NoAnxietyInChrist');
CREATE TABLE Encouragement(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, CATEGORY Category, TOPIC Topic, TONE Tone, MESSAGE VARCHAR(255))
```

Comment: Avoid concatenating strings to produce SQL statements. Use a parameterized "prepared statement" instead, and forget about problems like this one.

Comment: If you must, you can escape single quotes by duplicating them. For example, `INSERT INTO enc VALUES(31,'God is 35:4 ''Say'' Be strong.');` will insert the value `God is 35:4 'Say' Be strong.`.

Comment: @TheImpaler I am inserting rows into H2 from the console. I don't understand what you mean by using parameterized 'prepared statements' in the console.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you - your second suggestion worked :) Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape single quotes by duplicating them. For example:

```
INSERT INTO enc VALUES(31,'God is 35:4 ''Say'' Be strong.');
```

will insert the value `God is 35:4 'Say' Be strong.`.

Comment: can you explain why it works? traditionally we escape the quote `\'` but that fails here

Comment: Quoting the [H2 Manual - String Literal](https://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#string): "A character string literal starts and ends with a single quote. Two single quotes can be used to create a single quote inside a string.". It also explains that the backslash character "\" is used to escape 16-bit Unicode characters.