# Triple-quoting for Docker bash entrypoint

Tags: bash, docker, escaping, single-quotes

I have a Dockerfile with `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]`.

I am having trouble with triple-quoting.

None of the following commands to Docker work:

```
"echo 'New York\\\'s Finest'"
"echo 'New York\\'s Finest'"
"echo 'New York\'s Finest'"
'echo "New York\\\'s Finest"'
'echo "New York\\'s Finest"'
'echo "New York\'s Finest"'
```

Assuming that I need to quote the command, and there is a filename with a single quote in it that is an argument to the command, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you delete this `ENTRYPOINT` line entirely?  It doesn't seem to be necessary here, but it forces the `CMD` to be packed into a single shell word, which introduces the quoting problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
"echo \"New York's Finest\""
```

Answer (score 0):

in general your issue is with the escaping in the bash command:

please see explenation at: [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

and in the dockerfile you will need to get:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c", "'echo "new york'"'"'s finest "'"]
```

hope this reolve it for you.

Comment: I don't want to modify the Dockerfile.