# bash ldapsearch - escape single quote in password

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to work out how to escape characters in an ldapsearch password.

With the password set as `test!1234` the following works:

```
ldapsearch -h 127.0.0.1 -x -S 'ou' -D 'administrator' -w 'test!1234'
```

If I change the password `test!'1234` then this doesn't work:

```
ldapsearch -h 127.0.0.1 -x -S 'ou' -D 'administrator' -w 'test!\'1234'
```

I get `Invalid credentials` even though the username and password are correct.

How do escape the ' and any other characters?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Answer (score 0):

why don't use the variable substitution?

```
export mypass="test!1234"

ldapsearch -h 127.0.0.1 -x -S 'ou' -D 'administrator' -w $mypass
```