# Escape characters in bamboo script task

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, bamboo

I got bash script that is ran in bamboo's deploy step.

Script:

```
set -x 
 ls
 aws sts get-caller-identity
 for i in $1
 do
     echo "Modyfing $i in dynamodb"
     aws lambda invoke \
        --function-name my-lambda \
        --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
        --payload '{"command":"/opt/awscli/aws dynamodb scan --table-name dynamo-table --filter-expression "table_name = :table_name" --expression-attribute-values '"'"'{ ":table_name": { "S": "'$i'" } }'"'"' "}' \
        --output text \
        response.json
    
    cat response.json
done
```

The issue is with escaping [single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings), current solution returns error:

```
10-Sep-2023 16:59:51    An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
10-Sep-2023 16:59:51     at [Source: (byte[])"{"command":"/opt/awscli/aws dynamodb scan --table-name grs-suretybi-rr-glue-meta-staging --filter-expression "table_name = :table_name" --expression-attribute-values '{ ":table_name": { "S": "wbardm.invoice_type" } }' "}"; line: 1, column: 112]
```

Current output:

```
10-Sep-2023 16:59:50    + echo 'Modyfing dbo.table_one in dynamodb'
10-Sep-2023 16:59:50    + aws lambda invoke --function-name my-lambda --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{"command":"/opt/awscli/aws dynamodb scan --table-name dynamo-table --filter-expression "table_name = :table_name" --expression-attribute-values '\''{ ":table_name": { "S": "dbo.table_one" } }'\'' "}' --output text response.json
```

Getting this extra `'` that gets escaped with `\`:

```
'\''{ ":table_name": { "S": "dbo.table_one" } }'\''
```

while it should be:

```
'{ ":table_name": { "S": "dbo.table_one" } }'
```

Comment: using `set -x` not only expands variables, but it "normalizes" the cmd-line quoting. Notice how `set -x ; echo "hello world" now appears as `+ echo 'hello world'` (single quotes, not dbl). So your output `'\''{ ":table_name":....` is telling you "this is how I am interpreting the quoting you gave me. There are postings here that explain the fine points of quoting, but I don't have time now to find them. Good luck.