# Using a variable with an apostrophe in it when I am already in quoting hell

Tags: bash, double-quotes, heredoc, single-quotes

I am running...

```
xargs -0 somescript -C << EOF
drush ev 'somethingelse("$STRING",[]);'
EOF
```

`somescript` is a script I need to run and I do not control. It expects a command as an argument after `-C` much like `su -c` does.

This works if `$STRING` does not contain an apostrophe but if it does then it falls apart as it can be expected. I tried

```
xargs -0 somescript -C << "EOF1"
xargs -0 drush ev << 'EOF2'
somethingelse("$STRING",[]);
EOF2
EOF1
```

but this gives me `sh: syntax error: unexpected "("`. I do not quite understand why.

Ps.: Please do not recommend running something else: the problem here is running this script. This is not an X-Y problem, I have a screw I need to screw in. I can't use a rivet. I am asking where to find the appropriate screwdriver. Thanks!

Comment: Requiring both a `somescript` nobody here has seen and an external `drush` command makes this a bit less testable than one might like. If it's possible to build a stand-in similar enough to to the commands you're trying to invoke to allow a [mre] others can test to validate proposed solutions, that would be much for the better.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/4561887)

Comment: Regarding "Please do not recommend running something else" - we have to recommend running something else or you're stuck with your current script which apparently doesn't do what you want. Is there any particular part of your script that you want to retain?

Answer (score 3):

Your sample code is:

```
xargs -0 somescript -C << EOF
drush ev 'somethingelse("$STRING",[]);'
EOF
```

From the tags, this appears to be a bash command-line that is attempting to get drush to execute a PHP command.

You wish to pass to PHP a string to use as an argument to the `somethingelse` function.

Instead of attempting to do any kind of string interpolation, you can pass the value in the environment and tell PHP to access the value from there:

```
MyVar=$STRING xargs -0 somescript -C <<'EOD'
    drush ev 'somethingelse(getenv("MyVar"),[]);'
EOD
```

---

Note that textual string interpolation across semantic domains is best avoided. It is notoriously hard to get right, since the receiving code may not always interpret the result as intended, opening it up to the [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) class of bugs (including [many tainted input weaknesses](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/990.html) such as [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/); Shellshock; AI prompt injection attacks; etc.)

Comment: In general, this is a solid approach (knowing _what drush is_ is an advantage for you here). That said, I'm a little uncomfortable with the use of `xargs -0` with input that doesn't have any NUL terminator. Do you know if this is well-defined to work portably (at least, portably to everywhere `-0` exists)?

Comment: (you might want to make sure STRING is in the environment, btw -- `STRING=$STRING xargs ...` would suffice for that).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the two implementations I have immediate access to do understand non-null input but I agree, having one seems safer

Answer (score 1):

#### Using A Python Helper

The use of `sh` instead of `bash` complicates this a bit -- bash can escape arbitrary strings into content that *bash itself* can evaluate, but it doesn't have an equivalent feature that targets baseline POSIX sh; hence the use of a Python helper below to provide a solution that works on operating systems where sh is provided by ash, dash, or another non-bash shell.

```
# Define a helper using the python shlex module to shell-quote arbitrary strings
quote() {
  python3 -c '
import sys, shlex
print(" ".join(shlex.quote(s) for s in sys.argv[1:]))
' "$@"
}

# Store your exact/literal command in a string
# note you could also run drush_arg='somethingelse("$STRING",[]);'
drush_arg=$(cat <<'EOF'
somethingelse("$STRING",[]);
EOF
)

# Pass that literal command through the helper to quote it appropriately
drush_cmd=$(quote drush ev "$drush_arg")

# Use the result of that quoting operation
somescript -C "$drush_cmd"
```

You could even do this further: `somescript_cmd=$(quote somescript -C "$drush_cmd")` will create a `somescript_cmd` variable that can be `eval`'d to invoke `somescript`.

---

#### Bash Only (5.0+, sh compatibility not guaranteed)

If you're curious how to do this *without* needing Python: if the program you're starting invokes `bash` instead of `sh`, or you don't need to support operating systems where `sh` is provided by a non-bash shell, one could instead use:

```
drush_arg=$(cat <<'EOF'
somethingelse("$STRING",[]);
EOF
)

drush_cmd_arr=( drush ev "$drush_arg" )
drush_cmd=${drush_cmd_arr[*]@Q} # requires bash 5.0+

somescript -C "$drush_cmd"
```

---

#### Bash Only (3.x-compatible, sh compatibility not guaranteed)

If we avoid using 5.0+-only features, this would instead look like:

```
drush_arg=$(cat <<'EOF'
somethingelse("$STRING",[]);
EOF
)

drush_cmd_arr=( drush ev "$drush_arg" )
printf -v drush_cmd '%q ' "${drush_cmd_arr[@]}"

somescript -C "$drush_cmd"
```

Comment: when you use `cat <<'EOF'
somethingelse("$STRING",[]);
EOF` it puts the literal $STRING into everything.

Comment: @chx, correct, that is indeed the behavior of a quoted heredoc. Isn't that what you wanted? (If it isn't... where does the question say that?)

Comment: @chx (...this is another place where including a reproducer in the question -- runnable code, desired output, actual output -- would have avoided ambiguity, given a reproducer properly constructed such that the desired and actual output would only match if the string was expanded at the desired processing stage).