GNU Parallel not passing strings to MATLAB
I'm trying to use GNU parallel to run a set of experiments using MATLAB on our supercomputer which uses SLURM. I have a text file containing combinations of 4 parameters that are read in and passed to a MATLAB function. That text file is called gnu_parameters.txt and and has 4 columns separated by a single space.
fs_method data_name use_vars 1
fs_method1 data_name use_vars 1
fs_method3 data_name use_vars 1 

where parameters in columns 1-3 should be read in as a string, and parameter 4 is a number.
I want to run each combination of parameters in parallel to speed up the process. My SLURM script is below, but when I tell GNU-parallel where to put each parameter using the notation {1} {2} {3} {4}, I get an error that MATLAB doesn't recognize the variable fs_method. Looking at the log tells me that the error means fs_method isn't read as a string by MATLAB. To fix that, I tried adding single quotes in the SLURM script like so:
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --time=4-00:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --mem=1200g
#SBATCH --tmp=500g
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=115
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL,END
#SBATCH --mail-user=myemail
#SBATCH -p groupPartition
cd $WRK_DIR
module load matlab
module load parallel
export JOBS_PER_NODE=$(( $SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE / $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK ))
echo $JOBS_PER_NODE
cat gnu_parameters.txt | parallel --jobs $JOBS_PER_NODE --joblog tasklog.log --progress --colsep ' ' 'matlab -nodisplay -r "run_holdout_parallel('{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4});exit" ' 

Below are excerpts from the log file, the error file, and the output file.
Log
Seq Host    Starttime   JobRuntime  Send    Receive Exitval Signal  Command
1   :   1719498346.300      14.911  0   298 0   0   matlab -nodisplay -r "run_holdout_parallel(fs_method, data_name, use_vars, 1);exit" 
2   :   1719498361.751      14.387  0   298 0   0   matlab -nodisplay -r "run_holdout_parallel(fs_method1, data_name, use_vars, 1);exit" 
3   :   1719498376.666      14.385  0   298 0   0   matlab -nodisplay -r "run_holdout_parallel(fs_method3, data_name, use_vars, 1);exit" 

Error File
local:1/0/100%/0.0s sh: /dev/tty: No such device or address

local:1/0/100%/0.0s sh: /dev/tty: No such device or address

local:1/0/100%/0.0s {Unrecognized function or variable 'fs_method'.
}

local:0/1/100%/15.0s 

Output file
                            < M A T L A B (R) >
                  Copyright 1984-2023 The MathWorks, Inc.
             R2023b Update 7 (23.2.0.2515942) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                              January 30, 2024

 
To get started, type doc.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
 

                            < M A T L A B (R) >
                  Copyright 1984-2023 The MathWorks, Inc.
             R2023b Update 7 (23.2.0.2515942) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                              January 30, 2024

 
To get started, type doc.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.

But that returns the same error. How can I get these parameters passed as strings to MATLAB? Is there a better way to run these experiments in parallel than the method I'm doing?

Can you share the relevant section of the log and/or console output?

@CrisLuengo Yes, I've edited my question to include them.

Oh, I see. You might have to escape the quotes. run_holdout_parallel(\'{1}\',

@CrisLuengo Good point. I tried that and got a syntax error /var/spool/slurmd/job19168324/slurm_script: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `)'` .  I think the syntax around these quotes is the issue. I'm not an expert in bash :/

Yeah, quotes in bash I always do by trial and error, I really don't understand them. I think the {1} part must be outside the single quotes. But you do need single quotes to be passed into MATLAB. So maybe something like run_holdout_parallel(\''{1}'\',?

Currently in the log you see that the command run is matlab -nodisplay -r "run_holdout_parallel(fs_method, data_name, use_vars, 1);exit". You need to tweak the bash script so that this becomes matlab -nodisplay -r "run_holdout_parallel('fs_method', 'data_name', 'use_vars', 1);exit". Sometimes quotes need to be escaped twice (\\\') if they go through two steps of bash interpreting. Don't ask...

Apparently you can't escape single quotes. Here's a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/7328782 -- So it'd be run_holdout_parallel('"'"{1}"'"',, I think.

@CrisLuengo that seemed like it worked but nothing is showing in the log file. Could be it just takes a while...

I hate quoting. man parallel says:

Conclusion: If this is confusing consider avoiding having to deal with quoting by writing  a small  script  or a function (remember to export -f the function) and have GNU parallel call that.

So in your case make a function:
run_holdout() {
  echo This should run_holdout_parallel on $1 $2 $3 $4
  matlab -nodisplay -r "run_holdout_parallel(\"$1\", \"$2\", \"$3\", $4);exit"
}

When you can run that on the command line:
$ run_holdout fs_method3 data_name use_vars 1 

and that works, then parallelize with:
$ export -f run_holdout
$ ... | parallel run_holdout {1} {2} {3} {4} 


Thank you, that works very well and is easier to read!

The issue is how the quotes are being escaped. The way that works for me is
'matlab -nodisplay -r "run_holdout_parallel(\\\"{1}\\\", \\\"{2}\\\", \\\"{3}\\\", {4});exit" '

For some reason, using the answer in the comments
'matlab -nodisplay -r "run_holdout_parallel('"'"{1}"'"', '"'"{2}"'"', '"'"{3}"'"', {4});exit" '

ran fine but no commands were executed.

A few suggestions that don't exactly directly answer your question, but might be helpful to get your job done more efficiently.

Check with your sysadmin to see if you've got MATLAB Parallel Server available. This is generally more "efficient" in terms of consuming licences on a cluster - your approach will use multiple "full MATLAB" licences, rather than simply Parallel Server worker licences
If you can use MATLAB Parallel Server, you can use simple high-level MATLAB constructs like parfor to scale your work up to your cluster
If you don't have Parallel Server, you might yet have Parallel Computing Toolbox available, and therefore be able to run parpool('local') on the node allocated to you by SLURM
These days, matlab -batch is a much better option than matlab -r for this sort of thing.

